# zoom для SurfaceView сдвигается

Tags: android, zoom

Реализовал Zoom на подобии слушателя [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121145/pinch-zoom-effect-with-android-surfaceview) , но на 10" экране заметил что изображение смещается к центру после 5х увеличения и при 10х увеличении двигать изображение получается только в пределе половины от изображения. От чего такой эффект?